# how to show image from device in gridview with dates in android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am making an image gallery in android. I used gridview which can show the image in gridview. But, I couldn't show the image with a header date. Then, show the images according to date. I tried to show the image in layout with a textview. But, it doesnt work. Please anyone can help me. How to show images like below image.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    String appName;
    String name = null;

    //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View row = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        //convertView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(VIEW_TYPE,0);
        //gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.appsgridview, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.appIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        holder.ckbox =(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        holder.textView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);


        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    }

        holder.ckbox.setFocusable(false);
        PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(position);
        ApplicationInfo packinfo=packages.get(position);
        String namep=packinfo.name;
        appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();

       holder.textView.setText(appName);
       holder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(packInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));
       holder.ckbox.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
    return row;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to use recycler view with header layout for making this.

Comment: https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [StickyGridHeaders](http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/) where you can have date as a header